# OpenDSObject C# equivalent?

Tags: c#, ldap

I have a really old VB Script that uses OpenDSObject -

`OpenDSObject("LDAP://SERVER:389/DC=COM/DC=DOMAIN/ou=ORGANIZATIONAL UNIT/uid=" & user & "","cn=COMMON NAME","PASSWORD",ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION)`

I am trying to convert this to C#.  I am using the DirectoryEntry class.

```
DirectoryEntry uEntry = new DirectoryEntry( "LDAP://SERVER:389/DC=COM/DC=DOMAIN/OU=ORGANIZATIONAL UNIT" );

uEntry.Username = "COMMON NAME";
uEntry.Password = "PASSWORD";
```

I am getting an authentication error.
Does the Username property need the SAM Name?
Can I use the Common Name with the Directory Entry method?